# Logitech k400r wireless keyboard edge scroll

Tags: 12.04, logitech-unifying, wireless-keyboards

I got a Logitech k400r Keyboard with touchpad. Two-finger vertical and horizontal scrolling works fine but I find it very uncomfortable to scroll this way. The way I hold this device my right thumb sits comfortably on the right edge and it would be great to have a single finger edge scrolling, which does not seem supported by this device. Is there a way to enable this ?

Comment: I didn't even know it supports that, read the docs of K400 probably... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a driver that does that, but I found that by holding the FN key you can scroll with just one finger, which is a good enough solution I guess.